# IE8, IE7, IE6, height of td is 1px different

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table

```
<table width="320" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border:1px solid #d6d6d6;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td height="131" valign="bottom" style="padding:0px 8px;">aaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td height="10" style="line-height:1px;">bbb</tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="182" valign="top" style="padding:0px 8px;line-height:1px;">ccc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In IE6 and IE7, the first td has same height value as exactly 131px, but in IE8 it has 132px.

How to fix it?

Comment: Why using old IE. IE means troubles :)

Comment: Professionals still need to build for IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used a browser reset? This can help smooth out browser inconsistencies. Try either the mayer http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or the newer style called normalize http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/ this can help remove padding and margins which differ from browser to browser even from the same manufacture.

If you don't know what a reset is its a css file that you add to your page and it simply resets or put a number of elements back to their default setting which in many cases is 0, when everything in all browsers is reset you can start to rebuilt the pages css with more consistently.

If you have tried this and its failed, then you could add a class to the table then use conditional comments to fix the height of the table. Paul Irish's html5 boiler plate comes with the conditional statement at the top of the document which helps target all the various versions of IE within the same style sheet, so no need for IE6, IE7, IE8 style sheets.

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

cheers,
Stefan

Comment: How about use this technology in email?

Comment: Good point smoothdvd, in my experience of building html email you don't use browser resets as you can't rely on the email or web client from stripping out the css from the head of the document. Some clients allow css while others don't this link will show you support for the link tag. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: The only time I use css in the head of the page is when I reset values for hotmail, but this is declared in a style block at the top of the head of the html document.

    <style type="text/css">
        .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;} 
        .ExternalClass {width: 100%;} 
        .ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%;}
    </style>

Plus if you want to change the display of elements in the page you need to use in-line styling, here you can remove css properties and change them with your declaration such as line-height and font size.

Answer (score 3):

This should give possibilities for creating different IE verions

[This site should give you a quick fix](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) BUT probably **NOT** the best fix

Because that would give you multiple css files for different browsers.

But you should use the same code for differentiating classes of your html tag:

-article axample-
*( @JezenThomas Tnx for finding a good article about this [Reasons why no to do that](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/))*

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->

 div.foo { color: inherit;}
.ie6 div.foo { color: #ff8000; }
```

Comment: Don't do this, ever. Stefan Burt linked to [this Paul Irish article](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) which explains how to do it properly.

Comment: @JezenThomas Like I said in my answer probably **NOT** the best fix